# Redirecting to sheet or presentation when local notification touched in swiftui, ios14

Tags: swift, xcode, ios14

I have little app, similar to system Alarm. When alarm is triggered, notification comes up and when touched it suppose to take user to particular view (modal, full view, doesn't really matter). Touching notification works but it only takes user back to app not to specific view. All UI is in SwiftUI, however I dont know how to change state of "triggered" variable which should open fullScreenCover when true.

Code:

NotifcationCenter:

```
class NotificationCenter: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isTouched: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
       super.init()
       UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    }
}

extension NotificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate  {   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) { }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        isTouched = true
       }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, openSettingsFor notification: UNNotification?) { }}
```

AlarmView:

```
struct AlarmView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State var isAlarmOn: Bool = true
    @State var editAlarmSheet: Bool = false
    
    @EnvironmentObject var alarmVM: AlarmVM
    
     @StateObject var localNotification = LocalNotification()
     @State var triggered: Bool = false
     @ObservedObject var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter
 
    // MARK: - BODY
  
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
           
                List {
                    ForEach(alarmVM.alarms, id:\.id) { alarm in
                            AlarmItem(alarm: alarm)
                    } // FOREACH
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        removeRow(at: indexSet)
                    })
                } // LIST
                .padding(.top, 40)
            .navigationTitle("Alarms")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button( action: {
                    editAlarmSheet.toggle()
                } ) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
            }) // BUTTON
           .sheet(isPresented: $editAlarmSheet, content: {
            EditAlarmSheet().environmentObject(alarmVM)
           }) // SHEET
        } // NAVIGATION VIEW
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $triggered, content: FullScreenModalView.init)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                localNotification.sendNotification()
                triggered = notificationCenter.isTouched
                })
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
       } // VIEW
```

I simply made State "triggered" equals "NotificationCenter.isTouched" in .onAppear() but I think it's too naive and simply doesn't work.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, was really simple. Instead of using @State to present fullScreenCover I use NotificationCenter.isTouch which is published. Don't know I missed this simple solution.